# Scheme code to Haskell

Tags: haskell, scheme

I need convert this code to Haskell. Please help me. 
I would be very grateful for your help.

```
#lang scheme

(define (lab1 currentList counter result) 
    (let countdown ((i (- (length currentList) 1))) 
      (if (= i 0) 
          (display result) 
          (begin 
            (if (list? (list-ref currentList i))  
                (if (> (+ 1 counter) result) 
                    (begin
                      (set! counter (+ 1 counter))
                      (set! result (+ 1 result))
                      (countdown(- i 1))) 
                    (begin
                      (set! counter (+ 1 counter))
                      (countdown(- i 1)))) 
                (begin
                  (set! counter 0)
                  (countdown(- i 1))))))))
```

I think I need to use something like:

```
data PolarBear a = P a | B [PolarBear a] 

task :: [PolarBear a] -> Int 
task [] = 0 
task ((P _):ps) = task ps 
task ((B p):ps) | null p = 1 + task ps 
                | otherwise = task ps + (task p) 

main = task $ [B [ P 1, B [], B [ P 2, B [ P 3, B [], B []]]]]
```

?

Comment: What does your code do?

Comment: @SimonShine  Need to do without the use of standard functions: "For a given list to determine the maximum number of consecutive lists."

Comment: IIUC, the `list?` check dynamically tests whether something is a list. This has no clear counterpart in a statically typed language, unless there's a giant sum type around like `data Value = VCons ... | VNil | VInt ... | ....`. Anyway, this looks too broad for SO.

Comment: I would first rewrite that in Scheme (or Lisp), as it looks like it's already been converted from an assignment-based, non-list-processing language. (If you have list of lists - `[[a]]` - in Haskell, the number you're looking for is the length of the list. If you don't have a list of lists, the number is zero.)

Comment: Yes, this looks like a way to count elements in a a list where some but not all elements are themselves lists. Haskell doesn't allow for lists of heterogeneous types.

Comment: `lab1 ... = ... $ foldr (\x (counter,result)-> if (listP x) then (if counter >= result then (counter+1,result+1) else (counter+1,result)) else (0,result)) (....,....)  currentlist`. assuming a datatype to which there exists a `listP` predicate returning a Boolean result. Like e.g. `NestedList a = Atom a | Nested [NestedList a]` with `listP (Atom _) = ... ; listP (...) = ...`.

Comment: @x3kt0 "Need to do without the use of standard functions" see the above comment; then implement your own `foldr` and fuse the above into one explicitly recursive definition. --- maybe define `data NestedList a = Atom a | List [NestedList a]` , using a clearer name (`List`).

Comment: @WillNess Hmm. I need to use something like: 
`data PolarBear a = P a | B [PolarBear a]
 
task :: [PolarBear a] -> Int
task []           = 0
task ((P _):ps)   = task ps 
task ((B p):ps) | null p = 1 + task ps 
                | otherwise = task ps  +  (task p)  
 
main = task $ [B [ P 1, B [], B [ P 2, B [ P 3, B [], B []]]]]`
??

Comment: @WillNess In Haskell there are local variables?

Comment: @x3kt0 yes, you introduce them with `let`. as for your new code, the original Scheme code processes the  input list *from the back*.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Answer (score 3):

As [molbdnilo indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130789/scheme-code-to-haskell#comment56021742_34130789), that's a really wretched excuse for Scheme code. To really get a feel for translating Scheme to Haskell, you should first make versions of `counter` and `result` that are bound in the `countdown` named `let` and updated on each pass *without* using `set!`.

```
(define (lab1 currentList counter0 result0) 
    (let countdown
         ((i (- (length currentList) 1))
         (counter counter0)
         (result result0)) 
      (if (= i 0) 
          (display result) 
          (if (list? (list-ref currentList i))  
              (if (> (+ 1 counter) result) 
                 (countdown (- i 1) (+ 1 counter) (+ 1 result))
                 (countdown (- i 1) (+ 1 counter) result))
              (countdown (- i 1) 0 result)))))
```

Once you've done that, you can expand the named let out into a local recursive function. Remember that

```
(let loop ((x x0)) body)
```

is basically the same as

```
(letrec ((loop (lambda (x) body)))
        (loop x0))
```

Once you've done that, the translation to Haskell should be pretty much immediate. It will be really *bad* Haskell code, because Haskell's `!!` is every bit as horribly inefficient as Scheme's `list-ref` (Will Ness shows how to do it much better), but it will faithfully reproduce the original code's behavior and (terrible) performance.

Comment: that's not me, that's `foldr`! :)

Answer (score 2):

The thing to notice in your code is that it processes the input list from back to front, passing the info along in the same direction (in two variables). This is the same as what `foldr` does, when the combining function is strict in its second argument.

The pair which is the second argument to the combining function emulates the updatable "environment" for the two vars in Scheme.

I'm leaving spaces to be filled, since it's a homework.

```hs
lab1 ... = ... $ 
    foldr (\x (counter,result)-> 
       if (listP x) 
       then (if counter >= result 
             then (counter+1,result+1) 
             else (counter+1,result)) 
       else (0,result)) (....,....) currentlist
```

assuming a datatype to which there exists a `listP` predicate returning a Boolean result. Like e.g.

```hs
data NestedList a = Atom a | List [NestedList a]
```

with

```hs
listP (Atom _) = ... 
listP (...) = ...
```

If you need to present an explicitly recursive code, you need to write down the definition for `foldr`, and fuse it with the definition for the combining function above (let's call it `g`), turning

```hs
foldr g ... = ...
```

into

```hs
foldr_g ... = ...
```

then just renaming the `foldr_g` to your liking. The postprocessing step can go into a separate, "interface" function. Like so,

```hs
foldr_g z [] = z
foldr_g z (x:xs) = -- g x (foldr_g z xs)
                      g x r
                        where
                        r = foldr_g z xs

g x (counter, result) 
  | listP x = if counter >= result then ... else ...
  | otherwise = ....
```

Actually inline the definition of `g` into the `foldr_g` by interchanging the code lines and smashing the two definitions together, as

```hs
foldr_g z [] = z
foldr_g z (x:xs)   -- g x (foldr_g z xs)
                   -- g x r
  | listP x = if counter >= result then ... else ...
  | otherwise = ....
                   --   where
                   --   r = foldr_g z xs
 where
    (counter, result) = foldr_g z xs
```

and we call it as

```
lab1 currentList counter result =
  ... (foldr_g (...,...) currentlist)
```